# QGIS Redmine, adding a new issue

Tags: qgis

This may well be too far off topic, but I'm sure some here will use the QGIS Redmine issue tracking system. I've recently come to register an issue but keep getting the following issue.

[image]

Am I being daft or is there really no box marked 'Category' on the screen? In fact, there's no box left blank at all except assignee.

Does anyone use the issue tracking system, and if so can you let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I would contact the qgis-dev mailing list and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears in 2 cases:

1. When knowingly/unknowingly 2 Roles are assigned to a User. Method Overriding causes this issue.
2. **Select Project>Settings>Issue Categories** field if **blank** but if in Workflow field settings 'Category' field of a particular role is set to 'Required', as 'Open' status here in this case at the time of your defect logging, the particular validation error is triggered.

Kindly let the QGIS Administrator know about this error to resolve the same.